# How can i find the cardinal of the intersection, character wise, between two strings?

Tags: c#, string

I am working on a project that requires some string manipulation and i need some help.

Say i have two strings:

```
string1 = "1 2 3 4 5";
string2 = "1 2 4 6 7";
```

This is actually what most of the strings I will be working with look like.

I would like to know what is a smart, modern method, if any, to find the number of intersection between string of this type, something idealy like this:

```
//a way to create GetCardinal is what I am looking for     
int cardinal = GetCardinal(string1, string2);
//Cardinal should be 3 as the intersection is "1 2 4"
```

I am mainly interested in methods that work great for the type of inputs like string1 and string2, meaning sequences of numbers separated by blank spaces

The reason for not using a List of int's is because the strings are output values and I am expecting some character outputs as well.

Thank you,
Ciprian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split them by white-space, then you can use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + `Count`:

```
int cardinal = string1.Split().Intersect(string2.Split()).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.Split`, `String.Join` and a little bit of LINQ (`Intersect`) will do the job:

```
var result = String.Join(" ", string1.Split(' ').Intersect(string2.Split(' ')));
```

If you just need number of elements in the intersection, use `Count`:

```
var cardinal = string1.Split(' ').Intersect(string2.Split(' ')).Count();
```

Comment: Succinct! :) But use of String.Split is expensive. A more perfomant implementation would use a state-machine to read through the input strings.

Comment: @Dai Why do you think `String.Split` is expensive?

Comment: `String.Split` needs to allocate and copy memory from the source string for each element of the generated array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function of string plus some Linq

```
    int GetCardinal(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return s1.Split(' ').Intersect(s2.Split(' ')).Count();
    }
```

or if you could have multiple spaces or tabs:

```
    int GetCardinal(string s1, string s2)
    {
        char []separators = new char[] { ' ', '\t' };
        return s1.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Intersect(s2.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Count();
    }
```